# Scrolling using Javascript with css selector

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a little problem with scrolling pop-up window. I want to scroll popup which has div and some css code. no ID or CLASS.

HTML CSS Code

```
<div style="height: 356px; overflow: hidden auto;">
```

JS Code i have Tried

```
var objDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
objDiv[0].scrollTop = objDiv[0].scrollHeight;
```

same code works for classes and id's

```
<div class="123">
```

JS:

```
var objDiv = document.getElementsByClass("123");
objDiv[0].scrollTop = objDiv[0].scrollHeight;
```

It's an instagram like pop-up. i want to scroll using div or css selector (or both same time) using JS code

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("123"); is the correct form of the JS code.

Comment: div is very common tag name in most html documents, might be that you got the wrong div

Comment: i am using it in ubot studio and i added double conditions to find the exact div
<(tagname="div" AND style="height: 356px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;")>

Comment: cant we select css from get element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code would work if there was only one div on the page. It's likely that you might have other divs on the page and the div you're after might not be the first.

If you want to scroll all overflow divs on the page you could do something like this

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (let div of divs) {
  if (div.style.overflow.includes("auto")) {
    div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
    // break if you only want the first match
    // break;
  }
}
```

If not you could try to locate the exact div using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and specifying a parent (your popup) id or class name and selecting the child div.

e.g.

```
document.querySelector("#popup_div_id div");
```

**Solution based on your comments**

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div[style='flex-direction: column;']");
div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div style="flex-direction: column;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in viverra justo. Praesent in eros eget dui accumsan accumsan et suscipit ante. Aenean nec eros dignissim, luctus magna quis, rutrum augue.
</div>
```

Comment: `var objDiv = document.querySelector("div[style="style="flex-direction: column;"]");
objDiv[0].scrollTop = objDiv[0].scrollHeight;`

i tried this and it didn't work for me

Comment: `querySelector` returns a single element so don't use the `[0]` indexer. Also you have _style_ repeated in your selector. It should probably be `document.querySelector("div[style='flex-direction: column;']")`. This method isn't recommended though as the style for the div may change.

Comment: Not an issue i can change styling time by time problem is it is not working i tried this code as well
`var objDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div[style=flex-direction]");
objDiv[0].scrollTop = objDiv[0].scrollHeight;`

Comment: You're using `getElementsByTagName` instead of `querySelector` which does not support selectors. To be clear, what you should use is `var objDiv = document.querySelector("div[style='flex-direction: column;']"); objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;`
Also what exactly does your div tag html look like?

Comment: i saw it works for this demo but not working at Instagram where I am doing. However, i am attaching screenshot what i am trying to scroll so you can try it in the console and understand better [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/ptmfI21.png)

Comment: Here is post link https://www.instagram.com/p/Bz0jgdEBrS8/ need to open like tab and it will show popup. i tried to run your code in console and it gives undefine return